# How to download and show Firebase Storage Images using Fresco

Tags: android

Here is how i can download image or any file from Firebase storage

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-bucket-name>");

// Create a reference with an initial file path and name
StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg");

    File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Local temp file has been created
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

And Here is how i can show any image using Fresco

```
GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder =
                new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(context.getResources());
        GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
                .setFadeDuration(100)
                .build();

        hierarchy.setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.FOCUS_CROP);
        hierarchy.setActualImageFocusPoint(new PointF(0.5f,0f));

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(<imageUrl>);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setImageURI(uri);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setAspectRatio(1.15f);
```

So I want a download url or uri which i can set to Fresco uri in variable with name .

My question is how can i get the Image url from Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we can get download url from firebase storage.

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Now create the uri from  and show it using Fresco.

```
GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder =
                new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(context.getResources());
        GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
                .setFadeDuration(100)
                .build();

        hierarchy.setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.FOCUS_CROP);
        hierarchy.setActualImageFocusPoint(new PointF(0.5f,0f));

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(<downloadUrl>);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setImageURI(uri);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        viewHolder.ivImage.setAspectRatio(1.15f);
```